# "Offer use assert for change title of action bar"

Tags: android, android-actionbar, assert

I use this code for changing the ActionBar title:

```
android.support.v7.app.ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
    ab.setTitle("example");
```

but Android Studio says I must use this code:

```
android.support.v7.app.ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
    assert ab != null;
    ab.setTitle("example");
```

is it good the first or the Second code?

```
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 24
```

Answer (score 0):

> android studio say i must use this code

I don't think that's what it says.

The fact that `getSupportActionBar()` can return null is only a warning. Your code will be run fine without an assert statement